# Is the Forbidden Forest surrounded by a wall?

Tags: harry-potter

There are lots of occasions in the books when Hogwarts grounds are hard or impossible to enter. And while they give lots of additional magical protection to it, the main thing that divides the inside and outside of Hogwarts' territory is the wall.

But I was always wondering why no one ever thought of entering the castle grounds through the Forbidden Forest? The forest seems huge - it's big enough for centaurs, acromantulas, thestrals, unicorns and occasional giants to live there without fighting for space. Even then, there is enough space left for a convict on a run to hide, Death Eaters to put their rest camp, Hagrid to organize lessons, and four Dragons to be kept without bothering other inhabitants.

However big and dangerous the forest is, it surely should have an end somewhere miles away from the castle. Maybe somewhere in the mountains. Why not enter the forest there and pass through it to reach the castle? Or at least it could be considered as an option when you try to protect the castle grounds from unwanted intruders.

Does that mean that this huge forest is also surrounded by the castle walls as a part of the castle grounds? That's a strange thing to imagine as it's going to be huge like the Great Wall of China really and it makes the centaurs trapped in the forest like in a natural reserve.

Are there any indications in canon sources of how the Forbidden Forest is protected from the sides that are not facing the castle?

Comment: Have you ever tried just walking through a forest? It's pretty bothersome. I'm not saying this is the reason, the thing is j r doesn't really care if it fits and is big enough, the books were written before google maps and so on, but really, how is someone just walking through a forest in the middle of nowhere? The government knows about magic, so it's semi believable that there is no official business there of any kind. The number of random people in the woods is so small ...

Comment: “…it surely should have an end somewhere miles away from the castle”—you are trying to apply muggle geometry to a magical forest. Consider how the Fidelius Charm works (e.g. when hiding Grimmauld Place #12) or the geometry of the Room of Requirement. A magical forest doesn’t need to have an end.

Comment: @Holger There is no indication in the books that the Forest exists in some sort of other dimension, like the Room of Requirment. I believe geographically it's pretty much just a regular forest.

Comment: @Raditz_35 *"how is someone just walking through a forest in the middle of nowhere"* - well, even Muggles do that all the times, I did it myself, yes, as a hiker. It can be difficult, but not impossible.

Comment: There is no indication in the books that the Forest is “pretty much just a regular forest” either. In fact, there are lots of indicators that this forest is everything but a “regular forest”. We don’t have any indicator whether its geometry is regular muggle-style or special, well, except for the one mentioned right in your question.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191508/are-the-creatures-in-the-forbidden-forest-stuck-on-hogwarts-grounds

Comment: @ShanaTar Yes, but a couple of people every other year can be dealt with ... This doesn't sound like a problem to me. And even if you just ignore them, who is gonna believe that there is a magical castle with unicorns around it?

Comment: @Raditz_35 I am not sure what you mean. I am not talking about unti-muggle protection, but about very specific occasions when they were expecting unwanted trespassers, putting protection against them. Like when they couldn't figure out how was Sirius getting into the castle or protecting Hogwarts against Death Eaters in the 6th book. So I wonder if there are some special protection against wizards who would try to enter the grounds through the Forest.

Comment: Your update should really be another question rather than an update to this one so I have edited it out.

Comment: @Shana Tar "Does that mean that this huge forest is also surrounded by the castle walls as a part of the castle grounds? That's a strange thing to imagine as it's going to be huge like the Great Chinese Wall really and it makes the centaurs trapped in the forest like in a natural reserve."  All the branches of the Great Wall of China total 21,196 kilometers or 13,171 miles, which seems longer than any wall in Britain could be.  By the way, the wall is not the co fortified castle wall, but the wall around the grounds of Hogwarts.  Continued.

Comment: @Shana Tar -  Continued.  So: Great wall of China 21,196 kilometers or 13,171 miles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Wall_of_China  The Great Wall of Gorgan 195 kilometers,121 miles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Wall_of_Gorgan Hadrian's Wall 117.5 kilometers, 73 miles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadrian%27s_Wall  Antonine wall 63 kilometers, 39 miles.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonine_Wall  Offa's Dyke 103-240 kilometers, 64-150 miles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offa%27s_Dyke  Continued

Comment: @Shana Tar - Continued. The Great Hedge of India or Inland Customs Line 4,000 kilos, 2,500 miles.  There are many modern border barriers, more being constructed all the time, stretching for tens, hundreds, and even thousands of kilometers or miles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_barrier  Private properties like Hogwarts often have walls or fences around them.  Continued.

Comment: @Shana Tar Continued. The Walls of Benin allegedly total 16,900 kilos or 9,900 miles. Private estates such as Hogwarts often have long fences or walls enclosing them.  William Beckford's Fonthill Abby estate had a wall variously described as:  William beckford's Fonthill Abby had a wall 6 miles long, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonthill_Abbey  or 8 miles long enclosing 519 acres http://rictornorton.co.uk/beckfor3.htm or 7 miles (11 km)  long https://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?t=186745 or 7 miles  http://www.hvtesla.com/fonthill/

Comment: Nobody enters Hogwarts through the forest because doing so means dealing with centaurs, acromantulas, thestrals, unicorns, occasional giants, on-the-run convicts, Death Eaters, four dragons, and Hagrid.

Comment: I have to agree somewhat  with M.A.Golding it's not uncommon in the British Countryside to travel along side miles of medium height 9-12ft high brick or stone walls that enclose the parkland Estates of stately homes. They are high enough to stop anyone casually climbing over them.

Comment: @Sarriesfan In the USA Elkins Park near Philadelphia is a fairly ordinary older suburb, but it is perhaps the only place in the USA where you can see two great mansions only about a quarter mile apart that were at the centers of two different country estates.  The center of the former estate around one of them, Lynnewood Hall, is surrounded by an iron fence with a total length of about a mile.  There was a longer metal fence around the Whitemarsh Hall estate but it was sold for scrap in WWII.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Luton Hoo Estate near my home, which has appeared in films such as Four Weddings and Funeral, The World is Not Enough and Warhorse has an area of around 1200 acres that is surrounded by a brick wall. There is also the 5 acre Walled Garden close to the old main house that has higher walls.

Answer (score 33):

JKR's own drawing of the map of Hogwarts indicated that the forest is bounded on at least two sides by the Hogwarts wall, a road and on one side by a train track

We also learn that the forest "*extends*" in a broadly North-easterly direction.

[image]

The Forest is described by JKR (in another sketch map) as "Massive" and stretching out of sight.. You can also see the northerly wall of Hogwarts extending along the top edge of the forest to the edge of the map

[image]

[image]

The books seem to describe a mountain (range?) to the North-east of the castle so the forest may run up against the foothills.

> The sun was rising properly now [in June]; there was a rim of dazzling orange visible over the mountains and the sky above it was colourless and bright. The light fell upon Dumbledore
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sup></sub>

Comment: On the sketch the "Hogwarts wall" shown around the Forest, but not around the lake... I got another question now :)

Comment: @ShanaTar - The 'wall' to the south is a high cliff.

Comment: Considering the forest is described as massive, I wouldn't want to try to trek through it on my way to a war or to infiltrate, especially considering whatever lurks in the forest (besides the creatures we've already seen).

Comment: In the Goblet of Fire, Barty Crouch Sr makes his way into the Hogwarts grounds through the forbidden forest, so there must be some way in from the outside. I can only assume they'd hope the creatures in the forest are enough of a deterrent to people trying to get in that way

Comment: @Jsmith2800 Yes, I thought about that time Barty Crouch appeared in the Forest, but I assume he just was able to pass the security as he was an official jury and was allowed to the Hogwarts. It seems irresponsible to hope that a chance would stop an enemy to enter the grounds if they are really determined to pass. Centaurs do not seem to be bothered with protecting the castle and other creatures can be avoided by a skillful (or not so) wizard. When they tried to figure out how Sirius was getting in, no one seemed to assume he entered via the forest - they were relying on the castle walls.

Comment: @Parrotmaster I wouldn't either, but that doesn't mean no one would. Hagrid was pretty familiar with the Forest and knew his tracks there, so it does not seem impossible to walk pretty deep into the Forest. I am not saying it's an easy way to go, but why no one consider it as a possible way at all?

Comment: @ShanaTar "Centaurs do not seem to be bothered with protecting the castle": Perhaps not, but it is heavily indicated in the books that they ARE very territorial and don't take kindly to most folks trespassing on their space. Hagrid was a bit of an exception in this regard.

Comment: @Jsmith2800 It doesn't actually say that Crouch entered the grounds through the forest: *At last, one evening, the map showed my father entering the grounds. I pulled on my Invisibility Cloak and went down to meet him. He was walking around the edge of the forest.*

Answer (score 11):

At the end of *Deathly Hallows* Hagrid explains how he got back in to the school grounds:

> Smashed our way through the boundary by the forest, Grawpy was carryin' us, Fang an' me.

I take this to mean that he did not simply come in through the forest with no physical obstacle. It would either mean that there is a boundary (wall) preventing one from entering the forest, or that they came through the boundary *near* the forest but there is actually no boundary around the forest. If the latter, though, why didn't they just come in through the forest without having to smash through the boundary? Hagrid of all people should have no trouble entering through the forest.

I think it is therefore likely that there is some sort of boundary wall preventing one from simply entering the grounds through the forest. This could either be a wall that encloses the entire forest, or it could be a wall that runs through the forest (i.e. if the forest is so big it is possible that part of the forest is on the school grounds and enclosed, but the rest of the forest extends unprotected).

Note also Aberforth's comment when the trio want to enter Hogwarts at the end of *Deathly Hallows*:

> "There's only one way in now," said Aberforth. "You must know they've got all the old secret passageways covered at both ends, dementors all around the boundary walls, regular patrols inside the school from what my sources tell me. The place has never been so heavily guarded.

This too would seem to indicate that the forest is protected by the wall. Otherwise the dementors all around the boundary walls wouldn't really help if anyone could simply avoid them by going through the forest.

In any case, it seems clear that there is some sort of barrier around the forest, because throughout the series no one ever suggests the forest as a way to enter the grounds.

When, throughout *Prisoner of Azkaban*, everyone is trying to figure out how Sirius could get in, no one said "hey, maybe he came in through the forest". Similarly, in *Half-Blood Prince* Dumbledore asks Malfoy how he managed to smuggle Death Eaters in, and doesn't even consider the possibility that they just waltzed in through the forest.

However, at the start of term in *Prisoner of Azkaban*, Dumbledore makes the following announcement:

> "They are stationed at every entrance to the grounds." Dumbledore continued,

Similarly, Hermione later says:

> They're guarding every single entrance to the grounds.

"Every entrance" and "every single entrance" indicate that there are actually several entrances to the grounds, yet in the books we only see two entrances (the front gates, and the lake), not counting the secret passageways. Thus, there would seem to be other entrances that we are never told about. One of them might be the forest. So it may have a protective barrier, but also have an entrance. During the events of *Prisoner of Azkaban* and *Deathly Hallows* it would have been guarded by dementors, and perhaps by aurors during *Half-Blood Prince*.